# WPF Installer failed if anti virus installed

Tags: wpf, bootstrapper, antivirus, wix3.9, wix3.11

I have a WPF installer which is created using WIX, WIX Custom Bootstrapper and Burn. I have used 3.9 version WIX to create and compile the WIX file. I tried to install that installer in my machine which have already installed AVG Antivirus and my installer properly installed in it. Then I have updated the WIX to 3.11 version and compiled the WIX source file then build the WPF installer. Now, I tried to install my installer in same machine which have AVG Antivirus already installed in it. Installer failed  to install and exception occurs as follows,

Error 0x800700e8: Failed to wait for child to connect to pipe.
 Error 0x800700e8: Failed to connect to elevated child process.
 Error 0x800700e8: Failed to actually elevate.
 Error 0x800700e8: Failed to elevate.

I have disable the AVG antivirus and tried to install Installer which is build with 3.11. WPF installer installed properly in that mahcine.

Anyone suggest me on how to resolve this and any help would be appreciated?

Comment: If you are using wix 3.11 version you might also face this issue in your installer. this issue exists in the WIX setup itself. Please check this link for further information   https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/issues/5658